# Compute the convex conjugate of L1 norm

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am preparing for an exam and I'm having problems with understanding and computing the convex conjugate of the following function:
$$\min\{||x-z||_1 : x \in \mathbb{R}^n \},$$
where $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried to add and subtract the term $||x+y||_1$ inside the supremum, but wasn't sure where to go further.

Thanks a lot for all your help/suggestions!

Comment: By convex conjugate you mean the Fenchel transform of the function 
$$z \mapsto \min_{x \in \mathbb R^n}\{\|x - z\|_1\} ?$$

Comment: I mean $F^{*}(y) := sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N}\{<x,y> - F(x) \}$

Comment: Try to use that 
\begin{align}
f^*(\xi) &= \sup_z \left(\langle \xi, z \rangle - \min_x \|x - z\|\right)\\
&=\max_x\sup_z \left(\langle \xi, z \rangle -  \|x - z\|\right)
\end{align}